# How to return the pure value of a promise from merge-images.js?

Tags: javascript, arrays, image, loops, promise

I use [merge-images](https://www.npmjs.com/package/merge-images) and all work is fine. But for some reason it is impossible to display the result without the **__zone_symbol__value**. I have a data source. And I want to create a new array with already merged images.

My code looks like this:

```
let imageMerge = data.map( d => ({        
      pic: mergeImages(['data:image/jpeg;base64,' + d.pic, 'assets/img/123.png']),        
      text: d.text
    }));  

console.log(imageMerge)
```

And result console.log:

```
[
 {
   pic: {​​​
    __zone_symbol__state: true​​​
    __zone_symbol__value: "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgo...etc"
   },
   text: "Some text"
 }
]
```

I need get value from **__zone_symbol__value**

For example, this way can display normal result, but in console.log

```
mergeImages(['data:image/jpeg;base64,' + d.pic, 'assets/img/123.png']).then(b64 => console.log(b64));
```

But I need a clean result in a loop

Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the samples state `mergeImages` method returns a `Promise`. So you need to await it to get the actual values like :

```
 let pic = await mergeImages(['data:image/jpeg;base64,' + d.pic, 'assets/img/123.png'])
```

```js
async function sample() {

  const data = [1, 2, 3];
  let imageMerge = data.map(async d => ({
    pic: await mergeImages(['data:image/jpeg;base64,' + d, 'assets/img/123.png']),
    text: d.text
  }));

  const all = await Promise.all(imageMerge);

  console.log(all);

}

function mergeImages(...args) { // dummy method
  return new Promise(r => {
    const res = Array.from(args).join(",");
    r(res);
  })
}

sample();
```

Comment: how i can write result to variable? I mean globally. I need to assign this result to a variable this.newArr